# Jquery UI autocomplete on dynamic fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Kindly have a look at this screen capture.

http://www.screencast.com/t/GMGBy6QF9bP

as i have shown i am trying to use jquery ui autocomplete on a dynamically generated fields, autocomplete works fine with the main field i'm using to copy & generate dynamic fields. but when adds a new field the autocomplete not working with the newly generated field.

this is my autocomplete code

```
$(function(){
  $(".get-tasks").autocomplete({
   source: baseurl+"job/job/get_tasks_autocomp",
  });
})
```

I would like to get help from someone here to fix this, please show in Code how can i fix this.

this is the code for add new field

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=0;  
      $('#add_fault_fld').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" class="get-tasks job-tasks form-control" name="fault['+i+']" id="['+i+']" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');

      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  
      $('#submit').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                //url:"name.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_fault').serialize(),  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     alert(data);  
                     $('#add_fault')[0].reset();  
                }  
           });  
      });  



 }); //End
```

Comment: can you provide the code for Add More button, a jsfiddle will be helpful.

Comment: @kasperite i have updated the post please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm, ok try this and see if it works for you. I'm using prototype to attach autocomplete function to dynamic element.

**UPDATED**: Added jsfiddle for demo: https://jsfiddle.net/p7pdmbgf/

**UPDATED-2**: https://jsfiddle.net/p7pdmbgf/3/

```
$('#add_fault_fld').click(function(){  
   i++;
   var element = '<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" class="get-tasks job-tasks form-control" name="fault['+i+']" id="['+i+']" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>';
   $('#dynamic_field').append(element).attachAutocomplete();
});


$.fn.attachAutocomplete = function() {
   $(this).find(".get-tasks").autocomplete({
     source: baseurl+"job/job/get_tasks_autocomp",
   });
}
```

Comment: Not working:( please note that  my codes for generating the dynamic field & autocomplete in 2 seperate files

Comment: I attached the jsfiddle link to show you how it works. Two separate files don't matter as long as they are both included. I supposed `baseurl` is defined in one file but not other?

Comment: Thanks bro this one works but there is a small problem have a look http://www.screencast.com/t/VFRvHzvg

Comment: any idea about this small issue?

Comment: ah right, you need to attach the prototype to the static field too ie `$(function(){ $('#dynamic_field').attachAutocomplete(); })`. Also remove the  other autocomplete line `$(".get-tasks").autocomplete...` as it's not needed anymore

Comment: i have updated but no luck. please check the below post.

Comment: the code in your post is incorrect @greenarrow. See my updated fiddle for reference. You may want to read about how `prototype` works in JS.

Comment: i am new to jquery yet sorry, but i am still unable to get this fix. if you can please show this new updated version using my code

Comment: one more thing is it possible to prevent users editing the results of autocomplete?

Comment: what do you mean?your autocomplete source is not editable by user anyway

Comment: as you can see in my videos. i use this autocomplete feature to populate text box. by uneditable i mean. once a selection has been made by user, the value in the textbox should not be editable or customize,

Comment: the results for autocomplete feeded through records already in the database.

Comment: yes sort of, i can see the textbox is disabling, what if the user selects a wrong item & then want to select the correct one again

Answer (score 0):

@kasperite Sorry nothing happens here's what i did

I have changed

```
$.fn.attachAutocomplete = function() {
   $(this).find(".get-tasks").autocomplete({
     source: baseurl+"job/job/get_tasks_autocomp",
   });
}
```

to

```
  $.fn.attachAutocomplete = function() {
       $('#dynamic_field').attachAutocomplete({
         source: baseurl+"job/job/get_tasks_autocomp",
       });
    }
```

can you post the final code with new update please.